# INSERCION A BASE DE DATOS SQL SERVER CON PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, php5, insert

Hola estoy intentando hacer una insercion a una base de datos sql server con php. Ejecuto el programa y me sale el mensaje de que se ah insertado correctamente pero cuando voy a mirar en la base de datos no me inserta nada y no encuentro el error este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$sql = "INSERT INTO fed_ublextensions(MPK_EMIS_ID,MPK_RECE_ID,MPK_ID,DIN_INVOICE_AUTHORIZATION,DDA_START,DDA_END,DVC_PREFIX,
DIN_FROM,DIN_TO,DCH_IDENTIFICATION_CODE,DIN_PROVIDERID,DVC_SOFTWAREID,DVC_SOFTWARESECURITYCODE,DDE_REPERCUSSIONS,DDE_TOTALTAX,DDE_TOTALCURRENCYAMOUNT) 
VALUES ('a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4','e','5','f','6','g','7','h','8')";
// arreglo acentos 
$qry_code = utf8_decode($sql);

   // Ahora ejecutamos el INSERT en la BD         
   $recurso=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$qry_code);
$ejecutar=sqlsrv_execute($recurso);
?>
```

Comment: Ejecuta lo mismo sin  el decode: $qry_code = utf8.... ¿Qué resultado te da?

Comment: lo mismo sigue sin insertar edite la linea tal cual:

$recurso=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql);

Comment: agrega un `try catch` para ver los errores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo el siguiente código:
Así podrías capturar algún un error:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 
 fed_ublextensions(MPK_EMIS_ID,MPK_RECE_ID,MPK_ID,DIN_INVOICE_AUTHORIZATION,
 DDA_START, DDA_END,DVC_PREFIX, DIN_FROM,DIN_TO,DCH_IDENTIFICATION_CODE,
 DIN_PROVIDERID,DVC_SOFTWAREID,DVC_SOFTWARESECURITYCODE,
 DDE_REPERCUSSIONS,DDE_TOTALTAX,DDE_TOTALCURRENCYAMOUNT) 
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
// arreglo acentos 

  $params = array('a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4','e','5','f','6','g','7','h','8'); 
  utf8_converter($params);

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
 if( $stmt === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
 //Función para convertir a utf8
 function utf8_converter($array)
{
   array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
      if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
     }
 });

 return $array;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono a la perfeccion y ya pude corregir el problema

Comment: hola tengo otra duda resulta que ahora tengo que cargar los datos desde un archivo un xml para ser mas especifico probe el codigo y funciono con datos comunes pero cuando traigo los datos del xml como tal me los lee bien pero al insertar me genere este error:

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMSSP
            [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
            [1] => -16
            [code] => -16
            [2] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified.
            [message] => An invalid PHP type for parameter 1 was specified.
        )

)

Comment: Revisa las sintaxis PHP puede ser que tengas problemas con las comillas en los parámetros. Te dejo un link, puede que te sirva.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844800/php-sql-server-output-parameter-gives-error